# Jquery Tabulator lost cell focus after nested table bind and press tab key

Tags: jquery, tabulator

Using a Jquery Tabulator Table, I populate nested child table when the value of the parent row changes.

When I type something in the very first cell named "Make" and press the Tab key,
the nested table has been populated as I had intended,
but It lost the cell focus.

By right, when we pressed Tab Key, the selection cursor should move and should be selected at another cell.

But it lost the cell focus. Please let me know your suggestion.

```
<div id="tbl_BeamCageSchedule"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var JSON_DataSet_Empty_Child = [{ date: "", engineer: "", actions: "" }];

    var JSON_DataSet_Empty = [{
        id: 1, make: "", model: "", reg: "", color: "", serviceHistory: JSON_DataSet_Empty_Child
    }];

    $(document).ready(function () {        
        Bind_tbl_BeamCageSchedule();        
    });

    function Bind_tbl_BeamCageSchedule() {
        //define table
        var table = new Tabulator("#tbl_BeamCageSchedule", {
            height: "100%",
            layout: "fitColumns",
            columnDefaults: {
                resizable: true,
            },
            data: JSON_DataSet_Empty,
            columns: [
                { title: "Make", field: "make", editor: "input" },
                { title: "Model", field: "model", editor: "input" },
                { title: "Registration", field: "reg", editor: "input" },
                { title: "Color", field: "color", editor: "input" },
            ],
            rowFormatter: function (row) {
                //create and style holder elements
                var holderEl = document.createElement("div");

                /// remove previous nested table object
                holderEl.classList.add("nested-table");
                var row_element = row.getElement();
                var previous_nested_table = row_element.getElementsByClassName("nested-table");
                for (let child of previous_nested_table) {
                    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
                }

                var tableEl = document.createElement("div");

                var tableEl = document.createElement("div");
                var position = table.getRowPosition(row);
                tableEl.setAttribute("id", "tbl_ServiceHistory" + position);

                holderEl.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
                holderEl.style.padding = "10px 30px 10px 10px";
                holderEl.style.borderTop = "1px solid #333";
                holderEl.style.borderBotom = "1px solid #333";


                tableEl.style.border = "1px solid #333";

                holderEl.appendChild(tableEl);

                row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl);

                var subTable = new Tabulator(tableEl, {
                    layout: "fitColumns",
                    data: row.getData().serviceHistory,
                    columns: [
                        { title: "Date", field: "date", sorter: "date", editor: "input" },
                        { title: "Engineer", field: "engineer", editor: "input" },
                        { title: "Action", field: "actions", editor: "input" },
                    ]
                })
            },
        });

        table.on('cellEdited', (cell) => {
            MainTable_CellEdited(cell, table);
        });
    }

    function MainTable_CellEdited(cell, table) {
        var row = cell.getRow();
        var cellvalue_make = row.getCell("make").getValue().trim();
        if (cellvalue_make.length > 0) {

            var JSONDataForServiceHistory = [
                { date: "22/05/2017", engineer: "Jimmy Brown", actions: "Aligned wheels" },
                { date: "11/02/2018", engineer: "Lotty Ferberson", actions: "Changed Oil" },
                { date: "04/04/2018", engineer: "Franco Martinez", actions: "Fixed Tracking" },
            ];

            row.update({ serviceHistory: JSONDataForServiceHistory });
        }
    }

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vb4porsw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realized that 
 after I typed and pressed tab, the next cell is focused.

But because of the whole table is reloaded 
 due to  `row.update({ serviceHistory: JSONDataForServiceHistory });` code from `CellEdited`  
 the cell focus was lost.

So I used `renderComplete` function and re-focus to required cell.

Now it is working.

```
var JSON_DataSet_Empty_Child = [{ date: "", engineer: "", actions: "" }];

var JSON_DataSet_Empty = [{
    id: 1, make: "", model: "", reg: "", color: "", serviceHistory: JSON_DataSet_Empty_Child
}];

$(document).ready(function () {        
    Bind_tbl_BeamCageSchedule();        
});

function Bind_tbl_BeamCageSchedule() {
    //define table
    var table = new Tabulator("#tbl_BeamCageSchedule", {
        height: "100%",
        layout: "fitColumns",
        columnDefaults: {
            resizable: true,
        },
        data: JSON_DataSet_Empty,
        columns: [
            { title: "Make", field: "make", editor: "input" },
            { title: "Model", field: "model", editor: "input" },
            { title: "Registration", field: "reg", editor: "input" },
            { title: "Color", field: "color", editor: "input" },
        ],
        rowFormatter: function (row) {
            var position = table.getRowPosition(row);

            //create and style holder elements
            var holderEl = document.createElement("div");
            holderEl.classList.add("nested-table");

            holderEl.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
            holderEl.style.padding = "10px 30px 10px 10px";
            holderEl.style.borderTop = "1px solid #333";
            holderEl.style.borderBotom = "1px solid #333";
            
            /// remove previous nested table object                
            var row_element = row.getElement();
            var previous_nested_table = row_element.getElementsByClassName("nested-table");
            for (let child of previous_nested_table) {
                child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
            }

            var tableEl = document.createElement("div");                
            tableEl.setAttribute("id", "tbl_ServiceHistory" + position);
            tableEl.style.border = "1px solid #333";

            holderEl.appendChild(tableEl);

            row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl);

            var subTable = new Tabulator(holderEl, {
                layout: "fitColumns",
                data: row.getData().serviceHistory,
                columns: [
                    { title: "Date", field: "date", sorter: "date", editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Engineer", field: "engineer", editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Action", field: "actions", editor: "input" },
                ]
            });
        },
    });

    var LastEditedCell_ParentTable = null;
    table.on('cellEdited', (cell) => {
        MainTable_CellEdited(cell, table);
        LastEditedCell_ParentTable = cell;
    });
    
    // Re-focus the cursor after the table is fully loaded
    table.on("renderComplete", function () {
        if (LastEditedCell_ParentTable) {
            var cell = LastEditedCell_ParentTable;
            var row = cell.getRow();

            var currentColumn = cell.getColumn();
            var nextColumn = currentColumn.getNextColumn();

            if (nextColumn) {
                var nextCell = row.getCell(nextColumn.getField());
                nextCell.edit();
                nextCell.getElement().focus();
            }
        }       
    });
}

function MainTable_CellEdited(cell, table) {
    var row = cell.getRow();
    var cellvalue_make = row.getCell("make").getValue().trim();
    if (cellvalue_make.length > 0) {

        var JSONDataForServiceHistory = [
            { date: "22/05/2017", engineer: "Jimmy Brown", actions: "Aligned wheels" },
            { date: "11/02/2018", engineer: "Lotty Ferberson", actions: "Changed Oil" },
            { date: "04/04/2018", engineer: "Franco Martinez", actions: "Fixed Tracking" },
        ];

        row.update({ serviceHistory: JSONDataForServiceHistory });
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qz1kpe2j/